Form of conjugate prior on $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for Normal $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution
I have seen many postings related to finding a conjugate prior for $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for the normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. I am trying to derived an expression that has a rather simple interpretation in terms of effective sample sizes in the a way similar to the case where either $\mu$ or $\sigma^2$ are known. It is well known that the general conjugate prior is the so called Normal-Inverse gamma distribution.
Here a way to derive such distribution is by expressing the normal distribution as a distribution of exponential type in a natural representation. Thus,
setting $T(x)=(x,x^2)=(t_1,t_2)$ and $\theta_1=\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$ and $\theta_2=-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$, we have that the normal distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is has natural representation
$$f(t_1,t_2|\theta_1,\theta_2)=e^{\boldsymbol{\theta}\cdot\mathbf{t}-\Lambda(\boldsymbol{\theta})}=e^{t_1\theta_1+t_1\theta_2-\frac{1}{2}\big(\log\big(\tfrac{\pi}{-\theta_2}\big)-\tfrac{\theta^2_1}{2\theta_2}\big)}$$
with respect a measure $\nu$ supported along the parabola $t_2=t^2_1$. From this, we obtain a  conjugate prior and posterior with essentially three parameters:
\begin{align}
p_{a,\mathbf{b}}(\theta_1,\theta_2)&=D(a,\mathbf{b}) e^{\boldsymbol{\theta}\cdot \mathbf{b}-a\Lambda(\boldsymbol{\theta})}\\
p_{a,\mathbf{b}}(\theta_1,\theta_2|\mathbf{t}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{t}_n)&=D(a+n,\mathbf{b}+\sum^n_{j-1}\mathbf{t}_j) e^{\boldsymbol{\theta}\cdot (\mathbf{b}+\sum^n_{j-1}\mathbf{t}_j)-(a+n)\Lambda(\boldsymbol{\theta})}
\end{align}
with $\mathbf{b}=(b_1,b_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, and where the normalization factor $1/D$ is given by
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{D(a,\mathbf{b})}&=\int_{\mathbb{R}\times(-\infty,0)}e^{\boldsymbol{\theta}\cdot\mathbf{t}-\Lambda(\boldsymbol{\theta})}\,d\boldsymbol{\theta}=\frac{1}{\pi^{\frac{a}{2}}}\int^\infty_0 e^{-b_2s} s^{\frac{a}{2}}\Big(\int_\mathbb{R} e^{b_1\theta-\tfrac{a\theta^2_1}{4s}}\,d\theta_1\Big)\,ds\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi^{a-1}a}}\int^\infty_0 s^{\tfrac{a+3}{2}-1}e^{-s\big(b_2-\tfrac{b^2_1}{a}\big)}\,ds\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi^{a-1}a}}\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac{a+3}{2}\big)}{\Big(b_2-\tfrac{b^2_1}{a}\big)^{\tfrac{a+3}{2}}}
\end{align}
from where we conclude that the domain of conjugacy $E=\{(a,\mathbf{b}): a>0, ab_2>b^2_1\}$. Applying the change of variables $\boldsymbol{\theta}=G(\mu,\sigma^2)=\big[ \frac{\mu}{\sigma^2},-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\big]^\intercal$, we obtained the the prior distribution (in terms of the original parameters $(\mu,\sigma^2)$)
\begin{align}
q_{a,\mathbf{b}}(\mu,\sigma^2)&=p_{a,\mathbf{b}}(G(\mu,\sigma^2))|J_G(\mu,\sigma^2)|\\
&= \frac{D(a,\boldsymbol{b})}{\pi^{\frac{a}{2}}2^{\frac{a+2}{2}}}\exp\Big(-\frac{a}{2\sigma^2}\big(\mu-\frac{b_1}{a}\big)^2\Big) \frac{1}{(\sigma^2)^{\frac{a+6}{2}}}\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\big(b_2-\frac{b^2_1}{a}\big)\Big)\\ &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\frac{\sigma^2}{a}}} \exp\Big(-\frac{a}{2\sigma^2}\big(\mu-\frac{b_1}{a}\big)^2\Big) \frac{\big(\frac{b_2}{2}-\frac{b^2_1}{2a}\big)^{\frac{a+3}{2}}}{\Gamma\Big(\frac{a+3}{2}\Big)(\sigma^2)^{\frac{a+3}{2}+1}}\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\big(\frac{b_2}{2}-\frac{b^2_1}{2a}\big)\Big)
\end{align}
that is
\begin{align}
p_{a,\mathbf{b}}(\mu,\sigma^2)&=\phi_{\frac{b_1}{a},\frac{\sigma^2}{a}}(\mu)\gamma^{inv}_{\tfrac{a+3}{2},b_2-\tfrac{b^2_1}{2a}}(\sigma^2)\tag{0}\label{main}
\end{align}
where $\phi_{m,\tau^2}$ is the density of the normal distribution with mean $m$ and variance $\tau^2$ and $\gamma^{inv}_{\alpha,\beta}$ is the density of the inverse gamma distribution with shape $\alpha$ and scale $\beta$. From the expression above, the posterior distribution $q_{a,\mathbf{b}}(\mu,\sigma^2|\mathbf{x})$, $\mathbf{x}=[x_1\,x_2\ldots\,x_n]^\intercal$ is given by
$$q_{a,\mathbf{b}}(\mu,\sigma^2|\mathbf{x})=\phi_{\tfrac{b_1+n\overline{x}}{a+n},\tfrac{\sigma^2}{a+n}}(\mu)\gamma^{inv}_{\tfrac{a+n+3}{2},\frac{1}{2}\big(b_2+(n-1)s^2+n(\overline{x})^2-\tfrac{(b_1+n\overline{x})^2}{a+n}\big)}(\sigma^2)$$
where $\overline{x}=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{j=1}x_j$ and
$s^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum^n_{j=1}(x_j-\overline{x})^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\big(\sum^n_{j=1}x^2_j-n(\overline{x})^2\big)$
The expression obtained above is not exactly the one given in the Wikipedia article cited above which seems to contain four parameters instead of three, and I can't seem to reconcile my derivation above with the seemingly more general expression in the aforementioned article. I have two  questions:

Is there a more useful expression for a prior in $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ that has a simple interpretation?
Is the expression \eqref{main} derived above is used in practice ?


Edit:
In several textbooks I have seen, authors used a four-parameter prior on $(\mu,\sigma^2)$ for $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ of the form
$$\pi_{m,a,\alpha,\beta}(\mu,\sigma^2)=\phi_{m,\frac{\sigma^2}{a}}(\mu)\,\gamma^{inv}_{\alpha,\beta}(\sigma^2)$$
and then state that the posterior is given by
\begin{align}
\pi_{m',a+n,\alpha',\beta'}(\mu,\sigma^2|\mathbf{x})=\phi_{m'(\mathbf{x}),\frac{\sigma^2}{a+n}}(\mu)\,\gamma^{inv}_{\alpha'(\mathbf{x}),\beta'(\mathbf{x})}(\sigma^2)\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
m'&=\frac{n\bar{x}+am}{a+n}\\
\alpha'&=\alpha+\frac{n}{2}\\
\beta'&=\beta+\frac{(n-1)s^2}{2}+\frac{an}{2(a+n)}(\overline{x}-m)^2
\end{align}
My question was more about how this is done. After some algebraic manipulations, I can see now how the three-parameter expression I described at the beginning of my posting leads to \eqref{one}.
In \eqref{main}, setting $m:=\frac{b_1}{a}$, $\alpha=\frac{a+3}{2}$ and
$\beta=\frac12\Big(b_2-\frac{b^2_1}{a}\Big)=\frac12(b_2-m^2a)$ yields
$$\frac{b_1+n\bar{x}}{a+n}=\frac{ma+n\bar{x}}{a+n}=m'(\mathbf{x})$$
and
\begin{align}
b_2+(n-1)s^2+n(\bar{x})^2 &-\frac{(b_1+n\bar{x})^2}{a+n}=b_2+(n-1)s^2+n(\bar{x}-m+m)^2\\
&\qquad -\frac{(m(a+n)+n(\bar{x}-m))^2}{a+n}\\
&=(b_2-m^2a)+(n-1)s^2+(\bar{x}-m)^2\frac{na}{a+n}\\
&=2\beta+(n-1)s^2+(\bar{x}-m)^2\frac{na}{a+n}\\
&=2\beta'(\mathbf{x})
\end{align}

I do not understand what you mean by "more useful". The above is through the "natural" parameterisation of a family of conjugate priors. You are correct in stating that three parameters are needed to define this family. Most textbooks (mine's included) use four parameters with different scales on $\mu$ and $\sigma$, which is not miminal but still correct since this larger family is also conjugate.

If you squint, you can see some similarities between your approach and Jewell's "enriched priors".

@Xi'an: Thanks for your comment. My question came about after looking at some textbooks that use the 4-parameter prior $\pi_{m, a,\alpha,\beta}(\mu,\sigma^2)=N(m,\sigma^2/a)(\mu)\otimes IG(\alpha,\beta)(\sigma^2)$ for  $N(\mu,\sigma^2)(x)$ and state that the posterior $\pi_{m,a,\alpha,\beta}(\mu,\sigma^2)|\mathbf{x})=N(m',\frac{\sigma^2}{a+n})(\mu)\otimes IG(\alpha',\beta')(\sigma^2)$ with $m'=\frac{n\bar{x}+am}{a+n}$, $\alpha'=\alpha+\frac{n}{2}$, $\beta'=\beta+(n-1)s^2/2 +\frac{an}{2(a+n)}(\bar{x}-m)^2$. I was trying to reconcile this with the expression I obtained for the 3-parameter prior.

@Xi'an: I had just done some (tedious) algebraic manipulation and and I can see now how I can derive the expressions in my comment above from the 3-parameter representation in my posting. I will add this derivation  in my posting later.
